# Chef node not receiving attributes from inherited role

Tags: chef-infra

I have a hierarchy of roles that I am applying to a node to try and get it set up. They look like this:

- base-ubuntu

  - Sets up some apt repositories, defines some users.
- nodejs-base

  - Installs nodejs and npm. Defines some attributes.
- my-app

  - Our app is a nodejs server.
  - The role has the nodejs-base role on its run list.

I have a node that looks like this (output from knife)

```
ubuntu:~/chef$ knife node show my-app-node
Node Name:   my-app-node
Environment: development
FQDN:        <amazon>
IP:          <ip>
Run List:    role[base-ubuntu], role[my-app], recipe[my-app::start_apps]
Roles:       base-ubuntu, my-app, nodejs-base
Recipes:     apt, secret_file, splunkstorm, nodejs, nodejs::npm, my-app, my-app::start_apps
Platform:    ubuntu 12.04
Tags:
```

That pretty clearly states that the node does have the nodejs-base role applied to it. However, there is a critical attribute in that role that does not make it into the attribute list before the program runs. The role looks like this:

```
cat roles/nodejs-base.json
{
  "name": "nodejs-base",
  "description": "Provides a base role for an application server running nodejs.",
  "default_attributes": {
    "nodejs" : {
      "user" : "ubuntu"
    }
  },
  "override_attributes": {
    "nodejs": {
      "version": "0.10.22",
      "npm": "1.3.14"
    }
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[nodejs]",
    "recipe[nodejs::npm]"
  ]
}
```

In the recipe `my-app::default.rb`, when I try to do something like this: `node['nodejs']['user']` I get an empty string back. Running `sudo chef-client` on the target node fails for a similar reason.

```
Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
group[] (spicoli-app::default line 38) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: groupadd  returned 2, expected 0

 38:  g = group "#{node['nodejs']['user']}" do
 39:    action :create
 40:  end
 41:  # Explicitly create the user and group during compile phase so we can
 42:  # resolve the home dir afterwards
 43>> g.run_action(:create)
```

The `group[]` in the error output confirms that my nodejs user is an empty string at this point.

So what gives? Do attributes of a role not get resolved down to a node who gets the role from another role's runlist?

Comment: Have you seen the attribute precedence model? http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files.html#attribute-precedence

Comment: Yes it's worth reading the precedence model documentation. Took me some time to wrap my head around it. Bottom line chef does not support role based attribute hierarchies. The precedence is based on attribute type.

Comment: I've read over that document, to be sure. I don't see where it says anything about role hierarchies not being supported. In fact, it doesn't really mention role hierarchies at all that I can see.

Comment: Did you upload the role to the Chef Server?

Comment: try doing a `p node.attributes.debug_value(:nodejs, user)` in your cookbook to verify that the attribute isn't being overridden.  If I figure out why my node is giving me a `:not_present` for my node attributes, I'll let you know.